# Kinect V2 and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, unityscript, kinect-sdk

I **want to do**, what this guy is doing in this video..

Please see this **[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60lrGvpw6Vg)**
(Interacting a live human with unity interactive cloth)

**My Strategy So Far:**

I took a simple **3d plane gameObject** in unity, added an **interactive cloth component** and **2 Box colliders** with **hand joints** of Kinect Skeleton to attach a cloth. 
Then I added **sphere colliders** with **all 24 joints of Skeleton** Stream to make the cloth collided by my body but the results are unsatisfied.

**Problem:**
The cloth is behaving very strangely.. It jumps off weirdly whenever it falls on my body(joints). I am stuck here. I just want a sample or a jump start or any help of how to do that.

Comment: Some code would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Please always take into account that the positions of the joints reported by Kinect may jump or jitter. Render the sphere colliders so you can see their positions and better understand your problem; and apply a smoothing algorithm on the joint positions (a common technique is to store the last 30 positions or so, and average them), or simply enable Kinect SDK's skeleton smoothing options.